# Parse Text files and save data against some headings in database

Tags: python, text-parsing, text-processing

I'm working on a python(3.6) project in which I need to parse a text file,

My specific problem is:
My text file has some headings like **Examples, Input, Output, Explanations, Notes** I need to parse this file and take **input** & **Output** headings after **Examples** headings and write them at end of this file mean after **Notes** heading and save the file.

Here's I'm trying to get the next line of **Examples** line:

``````
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join('description2code_current')):
  for file in files:
    if file.endswith('description.txt'):
        old_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), file)
        print('File Path    ````` is: ', old_name)
        rf = open(old_name, "r")
        lines = rf.readline()
        # print(lines)
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == 'Examples':
                print(line)
``````

How can I make that change into my file and then parse it again to save data against these headings into my database?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than saving a file under its current name, it would be safer to create a copy-with-modifications of it. (Later, once you determine that nothing has gone wrong, you could rename the new file to the old name, if necessary.) If you think about it this way, you may find it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: How can I do that, can you help me with code, please!

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. Does the file *only* contain headings, or does it also contain non-heading lines? If the latter, then are the non-heading lines to be treated the same as their preceding heading? Should the 'Input' and 'Output" be *moved* to the end, or *duplicated* there? These questions would probably be answered if you gave an example case (input file and desired file). But make it a small example, like about 10 lines.